# Search using function/method name in VS Code Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I use PyCharm for my python programs. I have been trying out VS Code recently and have been liking it. One feature I miss is the 'Search Everywhere' feature in pycharm which allows you to search for function/method names across your entire project. You can even search for relative function names like `project.module.module.function_name` and it would show up.

Can I achieve the same thing in VS Code ?

Comment: The "Go to Symbol in Workspace" command (Ctrl+T by default on Windows) is the closest VSCode equivalent but you need to install a language server that provides the information and the quality of such will depend on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Command Palette (`Ctrl+P`) and type the name of the symbol you are looking for, prepended with the character `#` e.g. #MyClass

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files) should work for your case.

> VS Code allows you to quickly search over all files in the
>   currently-opened folder. Press Ctrl+Shift+F and enter in your search
>   term. Search results are grouped into files containing the search
>   term, with an indication of the hits in each file and its location.
>   Expand a file to see a preview of all of the hits within that file.
>   Then single-click on one of the hits to view it in the editor.

Comment: PyCharm's feature allows you to find where the symbol with the given name (or qualified name) is declared. This is completely not the same thing as text search for the name of the symbol (which gives you the declaration, usages, unrelated symbols with the same name, occurrences in strings and comments, and everything else which is not the symbol declaration.)